# In python, how can I make a program sleep based on the real-world clock instead of the CPU clock

Tags: python, sleep, clock

TL;DR; How to make a program sleep based on the real-world clock instead of the CPU clock without using `while ...: pass`

In python, I can make a program sleep for a certain amount of time using the `time.sleep()` function. However, this function follows the CPU clock which means if I make the program sleep for one hour and in the middle of that my PC goes to sleep for 30 minutes, the program will actually sleep for one and a half hours.

My primary intention in using sleep is to overcome GitHub API's rate limit. Therefore, when I make the program sleep for one hour, I want it to sleep for exactly one hour (plus the scheduling overhead).

One possible solution could be using `while ...: pass` until a certain time. However, this would keep a processor busy the whole time and that is something I don't want.

Is there any way to make a python program sleep following the real-world clock?

Comment: Are cronjobs useful?

Comment: Since your entire problem is that the PC itself sleeps, what do you expect to happen when the wake-up time would during such a sleep period?

Comment: in windows, you could use task scheduler which can wake the system at a specified time to run a task

Comment: @Aaron, Krishna while a task scheduler could be a solution, given my context it seems to be an overkill. I am looking for a 1-3 liner code (if exists).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, if one hour is passed by then, just restart the process. If not, consider the PC's sleep time inside python's sleep time (i.e., sleep for one hour at most). So, some condition checks are okay unless it is as heavy as `while ...: pass`. So far, David Camp's, solution seems to be my best shot, but, I will wait a while more to look if any more elegant solution exists.

Comment: "I am looking for a 1-3 liner code (if exists)" you're asking for a lot of functionality out of 1-3 lines... The more robust a solution you want, the more involved it will be. Also task scheduler is actually quite simple and easy to use once you've familiarized yourself with it a little bit. Most alternatives will more or less amount to : `while time() < scheduled_time: sleep(for_a_while)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [pause](https://pypi.org/project/pause/) module:

```
import pause

pause.seconds(3600)
```

Comment: Note that "a loop will be started that will continually check the current time against the end time" by `pause`. While this uses "logarithmic sleep", this is both using a loop (which the OP does not want) *and* using `time.sleep` with its potential to overshoot (which the OP does not want).